# Delete time from Date&Time Data in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image: image_1]

As shown in image_1, I have a column of raw date data that comes with time. I want to get rid of it so that it only shows date (as shown in image_2)

[image: image_2].

I can simply achieve this with the code `columns("A").numberformat="mm/dd/yyyy"`. However, I found this doesn't really get rid of the time but instead simply hide it. I'm looking for some VBA code that not only visually but in fact removes the time. The expected result should just be like image_2, but when I click into any of the cells and in the formula bar, there's no time shown either.

Appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using `INT`:

```
Sheet1.Range("A2:A19").Value = Sheet1.Evaluate("=INT(A2:A19)")
```

Or a loop:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 19
        With Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
            If IsDate(.Value) Then
                .Value = Int(.Value)
                .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:
Probably worth finding the last row:

```
With Sheet1
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value = .Evaluate("=INT(A2:A" & lastRow & ")")
    .Range("A2:A" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End With
```

Comment: Appreciate your idea and just a question regarding your 1st option. I want to make the code dynamic in terms of the rows. So instead of "A2:A19"(as that's just for illustration purposes), I want to incorporate a row number variable into your code. `row_num=range("A1").CurrentRegion.rows.count` and therefore I could interpret the whole range as `Range("A2:A" & row_num)`. But I am not sure how I can substitute the row_num variable into this part of your code `Sheet1.Evaluate("=INT(A2:A19)")`

Comment: I tried the EDIT code, but the time part is still there.

Comment: Probably didn't correctly qualify the `Range` with the worksheet is my guess. Also you'd still need to change the `.NumberFormat`. Note that a datetime is just a number, where the decimal portion is time.

Comment: You are exactly right that i need to change the `.NumberFormat`. Right now every datetime doesn't have any decimal portion. However, I do have another further question. The reason that I want to truncate the datetime so that it only shows date is that I want to use a autofilter to highlight all the dates before today and I don't care about what time of the day. So, for example, it's 6/9/2021 3:15 PM EDT for me, but I don't want to highlight those rows which are 6/9/2021. Weirdly, even after cutting the time portion, some of the 6/9/2021 rows are still highlighted.